# Mysql Subquery returns more tham one row, I need to insert the selected data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to "fix" this query:

```
INSERT INTO tblmypagepop (DID,MyPageName,GID) 
VALUES(77568,(SELECT PGID FROM `tblpageindex77568` 
WHERE PageName like "%new_vehicle_list%"),4741)
```

The query works only when the subquery:

```
(SELECT PGID FROM `tblpageindex77568` WHERE PageName like "%new_vehicle_list%")
```

has only one value, buy doesn't when I have more than one. I already checked others post that have the similar problem buy they query is different like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't want any limit, the subquery has 10000 records that I want to insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tblmypagepop (DID,MyPageName,GID)
(SELECT 77568, PGID, 4741 FROM `tblpageindex77568`
  WHERE PageName like "%new_vehicle_list%")
```

Try that.